# Reading internal hard drive which had Ubuntu installed on it, to be able to read on Windows 10?

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I have an old internal hard disk which I was using Ubuntu with. I would like to be able read the information using a SATA to USB converter as I have some old documents and photos on this hard drive.

Is there anything else I have to do except just plug the hard drive into the SATA to USB converter?

Comment: No -windows **can't read ext4**, but it works the other way around: Linux can read ntfs.

Comment: @kanehekili Windows *can* read Linux ext2/3/4 partitions with the addition of a Windows driver... but **DON'T** do it, 'cause it'll surely corrupt the Linux partition. Comment placed here also for the OP.

Comment: @heynnema - thanks for clearing this up. Haven't used Windows since 2010, so from now on I'd refrain from giving comments on old knowledge ;-)

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: Windows *can* read Linux ext2/3/4 partitions with the addition of a Windows driver... but DON'T do it, 'cause it'll surely corrupt the Linux file system.

Here's the safe way to do it...

1. Connect the old Ubuntu drive via a USB->SATA cable.

**Note**: *Some* USB->SATA converters can't read/write to previously formatted drives without a reformat (thereby wiping the drive). This is due to the internal chip used in *some* converters. If this is your case, you'll have to connect the drive to a physical SATA port on some other Ubuntu computer to be able to access your files.

2. Boot your computer to a Ubuntu Live Desktop USB flash key, or DVD.
3. You should be able to read/copy files from the old Ubuntu drive to your Windows C: partition, or to another USB flash key, or external drive that uses NTFS or FAT.